# Support of SQL Server Containers running on container orchestrators

Tags: sql-server, containers, contained-database

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/sql/general/support-policy-sql-server#sql-server-containers-running-on-container-orchestrators) states the following about the supportability of SQL Server Containers running on container orchestrators:

> Microsoft supports deploying and managing SQL Server containers by
> using OpenShift and Kubernetes.
>
> Starting from SQL Server 2019, you can deploy the SQL Server Big Data
> Cluster on Kubernetes. Review the supported Kubernetes platforms in
> the SQL Server 2019 Big Data Clusters release notes under the
> Supportability section.

Does it mean that all kinds of supported SQL Server containers are supported on OpenShift and Kubernetes or is this statement talking only about SQL Server 2019 Big Data Clusters ones as supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This: "Microsoft supports deploying and managing SQL Server containers by using OpenShift and Kubernetes."  is about SQL Server in containers.

SQL Server Big Data Clusters have specific dependencies on Kubernetes, and so can't run in any other container orchestrator.